# How to extract a particular word from a cell in excel that matches a list of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to extract a particular word from a cell in excel from a list (array) of possible values and return that matched word.

I have a list of products, but I just want to know the color. The color is embedded in the products description, therefore I need to extract it out of the item description. Here is a brief example of a list the item descriptions:

```
CORNER CCP 26" BARN RED
CORNER CCP 28" KHAKI
CORNER CCP 28" SLATE GRAY
CORNER RS EZ ANTIQUE GRAY
CORNER RS EZ 26" ASHWOOD GRAY
CORNER,RSC EZ,AUTUMN CEDAR
CORNER RS EZ 26" BARN RED
CORNER RS EZ 26" CANARY YELLOW
CORNER RS EZ 26" COASTAL BROWN
CORNER,RS EZ 26" COASTAL CLAY
CORNER,RS EZ 26"COASTAL CEDAR
CORNER RS EZ 26" CYPRESS GREEN
CORNER RS EZ 26" CLASSIC WHIT
```

I want to then compare that Item description with a list of colors I have and then just return those color names.

```
Amaranth
Amber
Amethyst
Apricot
Aquamarine
Azure
Baby blue
Beige
Black
Blue
Blue-green
Blue-violet
Blush
Bronze
Brown
Burgundy
Byzantium
Carmine
Cerise
Cerulean
Champagne
Chartreuse green
Chocolate
Cobalt blue
Coffee
Copper
Coral
Crimson
Cyan
Desert sand
Electric blue
Emerald
Erin
Gold
Gray
Green
Harlequin
Indigo
Ivory
Jade
Jungle green
Lavender
Lemon
Lilac
Lime
Magenta
Magenta rose
Maroon
Mauve
Navy blue
Ocher
Olive
Orange
Orange-red
Orchid
Peach
Pear
Periwinkle
Persian blue
Pink
Plum
Prussian blue
Puce
Purple
Raspberry
Red
Red-violet
Rose
Ruby
Salmon
Sangria
Sapphire
Scarlet
Silver
Slate gray
Spring bud
Spring green
Tan
Taupe
Teal
Turquoise
Violet
Viridian
White
Yankees Blue
Yellow
```

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx   http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP010342648.aspx    http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/right-rightb-functions-HP010342854.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Place the data in column A.

Place the list of colors in column B.

Place the following array formula in column C and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$86,MATCH(1,COUNTIF($A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$86&"*"),0)),"")
```

Note that this is an array formula. In order for it to operate correctly, first copy and paste from your browser window to Excel, then, with the same cell selected, click in the formula bar (or press F2) and press Control + Shift + Enter. There should now be braces around the formula.

If the string in column A contains more than one of the colors in column B, the first matching column B color will be listed.